# How to upload a file from desktop to jupyter notebook using urllib2?

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I want to work with a file that is on my desktop, for this first i have to upload it to jupyter notebook and i have to use urllib2. My problem is that we do not know how can I upload a file from my desktop using urllib2. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can open local files using urllib2 as:

```
import urllib2, os

response = urllib2.urlopen('file://%s' % 
    urllib2.pathname2url(os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(some_path))))
```

All you need is `file://` prefix and an absolute path to the file. The code above converts the relative path (`some_path`) to absolute and pthname2url makes the code work both on Unix and Windows.